# Why does sklearn's Chi2 test return different results when a feature is present or absent?

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, scikit-learn, scipy

I am doing text classifcation and using SciKit Learn's Chi-square test to select features. Reading about the Chi-square test, a word being present in a text should be just as predictive of a class as it being absent, since considering considering one or the other just re-labels the columns. But SKlearn gives me different results.

In the Minimal Reproducible Example below, the word `present` perfectly predicts a class among imbalanced classes. For simplicity, I set a word's absence explicitly, with the word `absent`. SciPy gives the same results for `present` and `absent`. SKlearn gives different results, and they are both different from SciPy:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.feature_selection
import sklearn.feature_extraction
import scipy.stats

def generate_data(size=100, class_in_focus=1):

    # Generate data.
    np.random.seed(42)

    classes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    probs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

    df = pd.DataFrame({"class": np.random.choice(
        a=classes,
        size=size,
        p=probs
    )})

    df["text"] = "" * df.shape[0]

    # Generate one word that perfectly predicts a class,
    # and another whose absence perfectly predicts a class.

    df.loc[df["class"] == class_in_focus, "text"] = "present"
    df.loc[df["class"] != class_in_focus, "text"] = "absent"
    
    return df


def chi2(y, x):
    """Selects features with a chi-square test.
    """

    vec = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(
        #min_df=5,
        #max_df=0.6,
        binary=True,
        use_idf=True
    )

    # Extract the terms.
    x_vec = vec.fit_transform(x)
    terms = vec.get_feature_names_out()
    x_01 = (x_vec > 0).astype(int).toarray()

    sklearn_features = None

    print("SciPy chi-2 p-values:")
    for category in np.unique(y):
        chi2, p = sklearn.feature_selection.chi2(x_01, y==category)

        for n in range(len(terms)):
            xtab = pd.crosstab(x_01[:,n], y==category)
            sp_chi2_val, sp_chi2_p, sp_chi2_dof, sp_chi2_exp = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(xtab)

            print("%.6f : p-value for '%s' and category %d" % (sp_chi2_p, terms[n], category))

        new_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {"terms":terms, "p-value":p, "y":category}
        )
        if None is sklearn_features:
            sklearn_features = new_df
        else:
            sklearn_features = pd.concat([sklearn_features, new_df])

    print("SkLearn p-values:")

    print(sklearn_features)

    #return sklearn_features["terms"].unique().tolist()

df = generate_data(class_in_focus=3)

chi2(df["class"], df["text"])
```

The result is:

```
SciPy chi-2 p-values:
0.032127 : p-value for 'absent' and category 1
0.032127 : p-value for 'present' and category 1
0.002490 : p-value for 'absent' and category 2
0.002490 : p-value for 'present' and category 2
0.000000 : p-value for 'absent' and category 3
0.000000 : p-value for 'present' and category 3
0.000003 : p-value for 'absent' and category 4
0.000003 : p-value for 'present' and category 4
SkLearn p-values:
     terms       p-value  y
0   absent  1.833879e-01  1
1  present  3.737299e-02  1
0   absent  7.598796e-02  2
1  present  5.495042e-03  2
0   absent  7.237830e-08  3
1  present  3.572249e-17  3
0   absent  8.350924e-03  4
1  present  3.676005e-05  4
```

What is SKLearn doing in the Chi-square test exactly, and why is it different from SciPy and textbook statistics?